# fig, ax = plt.subplots() meaning

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been using matplotlib for a while and I don't actually understand what this line does.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

Could someone explain?

Comment: Did you try reading [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)? Or is the question actually "what does `x, y = some_function()` do with the results of the `some_function` call?"?

Comment: You could take a look at this excellent article explaining exactly what you are interested in: https://realpython.com/python-matplotlib-guide/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`plt.subplots()` is basically a (very nice) shortcut for initializing a figure and subplot axes. [See the docs here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html). In particular,

```py
>>> fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
```

is essentially equivalent to

```py
>>> fig = plt.figure()
>>> ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1)
```

But `plt.subplots()` is most useful for constructing several axes at once, for example,

```py
>>> fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3)
```

makes a figure with 2 rows and 3 columns of subplots, essentially equivalent to

```py
>>> fig = plt.figure()
>>> axes = np.empty((2,3))
>>> for i in range(2):
...     for j in range(3):
...         axes[i,j] = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, (i*j)+j+1)
```

I say "essentially" because `plt.subplots()` also has some nice features, like `sharex=True` forces each of the subplots to share the same x axis (i.e., same axis limits / scales, etc.). This is my favorite way to initialize a figure because it gives you the figure and all of the axes handles in one smooth line.

Comment: Thanks, I guess what do I use for just one graph then....I actually only have one graph this is my code.                    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))

Comment: What you have is fine, `ax` is the single axes for you figure. So use `ax.plot()` or `ax.scatter()`, etc. to graph your data.